# React Router Route only render first route from config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I created a route config for `react-router-dom` following the official docs [right here](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/route-config)

But when I tried to implement my code, it only renders my first route from the config.

**routes.js**

```
import TellerLoginPage from '../TellerLoginPage';
import TellerMenuPage from '../TellerMenuPage';

export const routeConfig = [
  {
    path: '/teller/login',
    exact: true,
    component: TellerLoginPage,
  },
  {
    path: '/teller',
    exact: true,
    component: TellerMenuPage,
  },
];
```

I created a component to wrap the logic of implementing the props into the `Route` component from `react-router-dom`.

**RouteItem.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const RouteItem = ({ route }) => {
  console.log(route);
  return (
    <Route
      path={route.path}
      exact={route.exact}
      render={(props) => <route.component {...props} />}
    />
  );
};

export default RouteItem;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import RouteItem from '../../components/RouteItem';

import { routeConfig } from './routes';

function App() {
   const populateRoute = () => {
     const jsx = [];

     routeConfig.forEach((r, i) => {
       jsx.push(<RouteItem route={r} key={i} />);
     });

     return jsx;
   };

   return (
     <Router>
     // ...
       <Switch>
         {populateRoute()}
        </Switch>
      // ...
     </Router>
   )
}
```

What happened is that the only routes correctly rendered is the one mentioned first in the **routes.js** array.
But when I tried to render it directly in the `App.js`, the routes are correctly rendered.

**Direct Render - App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import RouteItem from '../../components/RouteItem';

import { routeConfig } from './routes';

function App() {
   return (
     <Router>
     // ...
       <Switch>
         {routeConfig.map((r, i) => {
            return <Route path={r.path} render={(props) => <r.component {...props} key={i} />} />;
         })}
        </Switch>
      // ...
     </Router>
   )
}
```

Is there anything that I missed lol I feel so stupid at this point

Comment: Did you check your jsx, if it producing the correct jsx syntax?

Comment: What do you mean "it only renders my first route"? What the path do you use?
There's two different routes with `exact` flag therefore in this example only one will be rendered

Comment: @Mateen i did check it, it produces no error on the CLI. And since the direct render works, I believe my jsx outputs are correct.

Comment: It might be because you are rendering your own component `RouteItem` directly in the `Switch` instead of `Route` directly. Switch might be internally trying to use something like the `children` prop to access each route but sees your component instead so it fails to properly setup the routes.

Comment: this line is wrong ==>  exact={route.exact}

Comment: exact=true or exact=false --> both show that exact property exists. (Hence conditionally render exact property based on route.exact)

Comment: @RamilGaripov as you can see in my routes.js, my first route path is `/teller/login`. When I go to `/teller/login` it renders the component. But when I go to `/teller`, it renders nothing. When I switch the order of the routes on the config, it works the other way around.

Comment: @TilakMaddy could you tell me where I did wrong? Because I've tried hardcoded it into true but the problem still exists haha

Comment: it should not have any value like true or false just argument should be give like <Route exact path='/blah' component={ MyComponent } />

Comment: @PatrickEvans thats what I thought too, man. But when we looked in the official docs, the docs used similar approach too by rendering `RouteWithSubRoutes` in the `Swtich`

Comment: @TilakMaddy Nonsense; the react router docs say `exact` is a boolean property, and setting it to true is fine

Comment: @ChrisG yeah setting it to true os fine but the problem is when you set it to false it still behaves like it is true, so you shouldn't pass the 'exact' argument at all if you don't want it to be exact

Comment: @TilakMaddy hey man, i think what you are talking about is the shortcut for the boolean props. Giving `exact` or `exact={true}` is doing the same thing, but thanks tho

Comment: The `RouteWithSubRoutes` is not a component though it is a function that directly returns a `Route` component,  https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/be6c8c8cb9b10806603d6d97d29f77faa5059055/packages/react-router-dom/examples/RouteConfig.js#L63

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @patrick-evans [mentioned in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62993630/react-router-route-only-render-first-route-from-config#comment111396802_62993630)

> ...you are rendering your own component `RouteItem` directly in the `Switch` instead of `Route` directly. `Switch` might be internally trying to use something like the `children` prop to access each route...

At the the [official example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/route-config), they use spread syntax (`<RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} />`) instead of pass `route` as `route` prop: `<RouteItem route={r} key={i} />)`. Therefore `Switch` can access to route props in the example, but can't in your code.

You should just fix `<RouteItem route={r} key={i} />)` to `<RouteItem {...r} key={i} />)` and it should work. And of course change your own component to `const RouteItem = (route) => {...`

Comment: BRO YOU ARE A HERO. but whats the difference between using spread and directly giving it props like `route={r}`

Comment: The difference is that `Switch` can access to children props to define which of routes it should render. In your case it should access like this `child.props.route.path`, but because of `Switch` supposed that children would be like `Route` component it does only something like `child.props.path` (the [prove](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Switch.js#L31))

Comment: oh i see, what i did was i omitted the needed props from the children. thank you much man!